# Scraping worldometers homepage to pull COVID-19 table data but values doesn't pulls incorrectly (Python)

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

I'm scraping worldometers home page to pull the data in the table in Python, but I am struggling as the values aren't pulling in correctly. (The strings are... (Country: USA, Spain, Italy...).

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

url="https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
#Create a handle, page, to handle the contents of the website
page = requests.get(url)
#Store the contents of the website under doc
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
#Parse data that are stored between <tr>..</tr> of HTML
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

#Create empty list
col=[]
colLen = len(tr_elements[1])
i=0
#For each row, store each first element (header) and an empty list
for t in tr_elements[0]:
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()
    print ('%d:"%s"'%(i,name))
    col.append((name,[]))

print(colLen)


#Since out first row is the header, data is stored on the second row onwards

for j in range(1,len(tr_elements)):
    #T is our j'th row
    T=tr_elements[j]

    if len(T)!=len(tr_elements[0]): break

    #i is the index of our column
    i=0
    #Iterate through each element of the row
    for t in T.iterchildren():
        data=t.text_content() 
        #Append the data to the empty list of the i'th column
        col[i][1].append(data)
        #Increment i for the next column
        i+=1

Dict={title:column for (title,column) in col}
df=pd.DataFrame(Dict)
df.head()

#Print Total Cases Col (this is incorrect when comparing to the webpage)
print(col[1][0:])

#Print Country Col (this is correct)
print(col[0][0:])
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Please help to solve the issue. I'm also open for suggestion to do this another way :)

[Data Table on Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zZEW.png)

[Command Prompt output for Country ( Correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUZmU.png)

[Command Prompt output for Total Cases ( incorrect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9vId.png)

Comment: I ran this code. Seems correct. Why do you think it is incorrect? Please note values update/change every time you scrape them.

Comment: If it is an HTML table, I would pass the url to ```pandas.read_html``` and let pandas do the parsing for you. You can also download the page with requests and pass ```page.content```.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I haven't worked with pandas. I tried to figure it out online. I tried implementing pandas.read_html, but it gives me a list of errors @EricTruett